# Accessing the "created_at" timestamp of a pivot table entry

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need the value of the `pivot_created_at` timestamp in a pivot table entry I read out.

[image]

Accessing the pivot table data is already done and I use Eloquent for doing so:

```
    public function states() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Classes\DispatchState')->withTimestamps();
    }

public function getStatesForDispatch($dispatchReference) {
    $dispatch = new Dispatch();
    $dispatch = $dispatch->getDispatch($dispatchReference);
    $statusArray = [];
    $states = $dispatch->states()->get();

    foreach ($states as $status) {
        $statusArray[] = $status;
    }

    return $statusArray;
}
```

But how do I get access to this `pivot_created_at` entry to read out the timestamp? I am kind of stuck at the moment.

Comment: These questions... why would you not read documentation? If its not there go to https://laravel.com/api/5.2/ and search for pivot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). The way to access the pivot data is:

```
$user = User::find(1);

foreach ($user->roles as $role)
{
    echo $role->pivot->created_at;
}
```

So in your case it would be:

```
public function getStatesForDispatch($dispatchReference) {
    $dispatch = new Dispatch();
    $dispatch = $dispatch->getDispatch($dispatchReference);

    // ->all gets the internal array from the Laravel Collection
    $statusArray = $dispatch->states->all();


    foreach ($statusArray as $status) 
    {
        $createdAt = $status->pivot->created_at;
        // do something with the created_at from the pivot table
    }

    return $statusArray;
}
```